# Getting error in Pygame: music not loaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, playback

I'm using pygame with Python 3.2 and I want to play a music with this code:

```
music = input('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\themusicfile.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.load(music)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

However, this always return error'pygame error music not loaded'.I tried both \ and / and always same error.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should be using `input`. That will just give you a prompt (see [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input)) so, when you hit enter, `music` is just an empty string so there's nothing for the mixer to load.

You could try:

```
music = r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\themusicfile.ogg'
pygame.mixer.music.load(music)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

NB I've set `music` as a raw string so that you can use a single backslash.

I assume you've already initialised the mixer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and song must be in .wav format:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('song.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```